# How can I shuffle the indices of certain variables?

Tags: replacement, permutation

I am recursively defining rational expressions in two sets of variables $x_i$ and $y_i$.  Specifically, for $m<n$, I am interested in replacing all degree-$m$ monomials of the following form: $$\prod_{i=1}^m \xi_i, \text{ where }\xi_i \in \{x_i,y_i\}.$$

I need to code the replacement rule $$\prod_{i=1}^m \xi_i \mapsto \sum_\sigma\prod_{j=1}^n \zeta_j, \text{ where }\zeta_j \in \{x_j,y_j\};$$ this sum is over all functions ("shuffles"?) $\sigma:[m]\rightarrow [n]$ where $\sigma(1)<\cdots <\sigma(m)$, and the replacement rule is: $$\zeta_j = \begin{cases} y_j,&\sigma(i)=j \: \text{ and } \:\xi_i=y_i\\x_j & \text{else}.\end{cases}$$

If I knew how to code such a shuffle function $\sigma:[m]\rightarrow [n]$, then maybe I could use `Replace` and be fine, but short of that, implementing the sum over the shuffles is beyond my current knowledge.  Is there a good approach to coding this up, or should I somehow reformulate my notation to make it more amenable to Mathematica?

Comment: Read the documentation for [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html), [`InversePermutation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InversePermutation.html), [`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html), and [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html). It is not difficult to shuffle something.

Comment: If $\sigma(1)<\cdots <\sigma(m)$ then the shuffle is just the identity isn't it?

Comment: Well, $n>m$, so the kind of function I mean would inject $\{1,\dots,m\}$ into $\{1,\dots,n\}$.  Perhaps by the strict definition of "shuffle," I should speak of shuffling the sets $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\{m+1,\dots,n\}$.